# Pointer to User gives Sign Up Error

Tags: parse-platform

I'm writing in Obj-C using Parse. I've run into a problem where I use a Class (lets call it Transactions) that uses a column called "user" that is a Pointer to the _User class. However when I try to save PFObjects into Transactions with a [PFUser currentUser] Object for user Key, I get the sign up error: email address as already been taken.

The problem doesn't happened today but it happened yesterday with the exact same code.

**EDIT:**
As of right now, my facebook signed up account works fine but normally signed up account gives the error: invalid email address (code: 125, version: 1.5.0). If the error message appears twice then the object is not saved, however sometimes it only gives the above error message once, the object is successfully saved.

**EDIT2:**

```
-(void) createTransaction:(PFObject *)bundleObject {
PFObject *transactionObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Transactions"];
[transactionObject setObject:bundleObject forKey:@"bundle"];
[transactionObject setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"user"];
[transactionObject setObject:[PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLocation:self.currentLocation] forKey:@"delivryLocation"];
[transactionObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        [self createOrder:transactionObject];
        NSLog(@"Info (Parse): Transaction Object has been successfully created.");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error (Parse): %@",error);
    }
}];
NSLog(@"Created Transaction");}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you signup your user and where you save your Transactions object ?

Comment: added the code above and a link to the code

Comment: The problem probably comes from somewhere else. If the error appears twice, then the completion block is called twice, which means that createTransaction: is called twice.